# Question regarding terminlogy and wording of the derivative

Tags: calculus, notation

When doing calculus, we typically say that we "take the derivative of a function f(x)." However, rigorously, f(x) is not a function but rather the value of the function f evaluated at x. Thus, in order for this wording to be correct shouldn't we have to write something like $\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx}(x↦f(x))$ instead of $\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx}f(x)$, or  $D(x↦f(x))$ instead of $Df(x)$? If we are actually taking the derivative of the "function," then wouldn't using $x↦f(x)$ as the input to the differentiation operator be the most rigorous way to write it? Do we just use $f(x)$ because it it is easier?

Comment: It seems to me that $f(x)$ is an overloaded string that sometimes means the function $f$ applied to a value $x$, and sometimes means the mapping $f$, expressed using $x$ as a "dummy" parameter.  We usually know which is intended from the context, and in the case of the derivative, it is frequently the latter. ¶ At any rate, for better or worse, mild abuses of notation are common in calculus.

Comment: If you read $Df(x)$ as $(Df)(x)$ is it consistent. I would write 'take the derivative of $f$ (or $x \mapsto f(x)$)'.

Comment: We could write $\frac{d}{dx}(x\mapsto f(x))=(x\mapsto f^\prime(x))$ but mathematical notation is all about abbreviation.